# PLSQL - Concatenate two strings and split into 3 strings on condition

Tags: string, plsql, concatenation, divide

In PL-SQL, I want to concatenate two strings taken from 2 columns (address line 1, address line 2, max 45 characters each) into 3 strings (address line 1, address line 2, address line 3, maximum 34 characters each) based on the condition that no word should cut in the middle. for example:

If address line 1 contains:

```
1, abc park, def chowk, ghi marg c-123 street
```

and address line 2 contains:

```
city mumbai, pin - 435353
```

Combined with numbering to show where 34 characters falls:

```
         1111111111222222222233333         1111111111222222222233333
12345678901234567890123456789012341234567890123456789012345678901234123
1, abc park, def chowk, ghi marg c-123 street city mumbai, pin - 435353
```

The result should be like this

Add1 (max 34 char):

```
1, abc park, def chowk, ghi marg
```

Add2 (max 34 char):

```
c-123 street city mumbai,
```

Add3 (max 34 char):

```
pin - 435353
```

Comment: That would be string splitting, not concatenation.

Comment: The concatenation operator is `||` and the substring operator is SUBSTR().  But, as gkubed points out, you're actually trying to split on word boundaries.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing to show the combined line with a number scale to show where 34 characters falls.  You said no word should break on the middle so add3 should really break on the space between the dash and the number.  Your example shows it breaking on the space after the comma.  Add1 breaks on a plain space.  Please define the rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REGEXP_SUBSTR() can be used to solve this for you. As I said in my comment to your original post, your text says don't break in a word but your example shows ADD3 breaking after the last comma/space, not just space so you need to define your rule further (Maybe when it's the last section after the last comma only?).  Anyway, sticking with what you wrote, the regex gives either the 1st, 2nd or 3rd occurrence of up to 34 characters that are followed by a character that is not a whitespace, followed by a whitespace character or the end of the line.

```
SQL> with tbl(addr) as (
     select '1, abc park, def chowk, ghi marg c-123 street city mumbai, pin - 435353'
     from dual
   )
   select regexp_substr(addr, '(.{0,34}\S)(\s|$)', 1, 1) add1,
          regexp_substr(addr, '(.{0,34}\S)(\s|$)', 1, 2) add2,
          regexp_substr(addr, '(.{0,34}\S)(\s|$)', 1, 3) add3
   from tbl;

ADD1                              ADD2                             ADD3
--------------------------------- -------------------------------- ------
1, abc park, def chowk, ghi marg  c-123 street city mumbai, pin -  435353

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I have written this function which split a text into fixed length lines without truncating words.

pi_text : Your unwrapped text

pi_max_line : Line length you want to split

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wrap_to_paragraph(pi_text          VARCHAR2,
                                             pi_max_line      PLS_INTEGER,
                                             pi_end_paragraph VARCHAR2 DEFAULT CHR(10)) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

  TYPE paragraph_tabletype_aat IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  l_loc_para  paragraph_tabletype_aat;
  l_loc_lines INTEGER;
  l_return    VARCHAR2(32767);

  PROCEDURE to_paragraph(pi_text_in          IN VARCHAR2,
                         pi_line_length      IN INTEGER,
                         po_paragraph_out    IN OUT paragraph_tabletype_aat,
                         pio_num_lines_out   IN OUT INTEGER,
                         pi_word_break_at_in IN VARCHAR2 := ' ') IS

    l_len_text       INTEGER := LENGTH(pi_text_in);
    l_line_start_loc INTEGER := 1;
    l_line_end_loc   INTEGER := 1;
    l_last_space_loc INTEGER;
    l_curr_line      VARCHAR2(100);
    l_replace_string VARCHAR2(100) := NULL;

    PROCEDURE set_replace_string IS
    BEGIN
      l_replace_string := RPAD('@', LENGTH(pi_word_break_at_in), '@');
    END set_replace_string;

    PROCEDURE find_last_delim_loc(pi_line_in IN VARCHAR2,
                                  po_loc_out OUT INTEGER) IS
      l_line VARCHAR2(1000) := pi_line_in;
    BEGIN
      IF pi_word_break_at_in IS NOT NULL
      THEN
        l_line := translate(pi_line_in, pi_word_break_at_in, l_replace_string);
      END IF;
      po_loc_out := INSTR(l_line, '@', -1);
    END find_last_delim_loc;

  BEGIN
    set_replace_string;

    IF l_len_text IS NULL
    THEN
      pio_num_lines_out := 0;
    ELSE
      pio_num_lines_out := 1;

      LOOP
        EXIT WHEN l_line_end_loc > l_len_text;
        l_line_end_loc := LEAST(l_line_end_loc + pi_line_length, l_len_text + 1);

        /* get the next possible line of text */
        l_curr_line := SUBSTRB(pi_text_in || ' ', l_line_start_loc, pi_line_length + 1);

        /* find the last space in this section of the line */
        find_last_delim_loc(l_curr_line, l_last_space_loc);

        /* When NO spaces exist, use the full current line*/
        /* otherwise, cut the line at the space.          */
        IF l_last_space_loc > 0
        THEN
          l_line_end_loc := l_line_start_loc + l_last_space_loc;
        END IF;

        IF INSTR(l_curr_line, pi_end_paragraph) > 0
        THEN
          l_line_end_loc := l_line_start_loc + INSTR(l_curr_line, pi_end_paragraph) + 1;
        END IF;

        /* Add this line to the paragraph */
        po_paragraph_out(pio_num_lines_out) := REPLACE(SUBSTRB(pi_text_in,
                                                               l_line_start_loc,
                                                               l_line_end_loc - l_line_start_loc),
                                                       pi_end_paragraph);

        pio_num_lines_out := pio_num_lines_out + 1;
        l_line_start_loc  := l_line_end_loc;
      END LOOP;

      pio_num_lines_out := pio_num_lines_out - 1;

    END IF;
  END to_paragraph;

BEGIN

  /* Return original */
  IF (pi_max_line = 0 OR pi_max_line > 99)
  THEN
    RETURN pi_text;
  END IF;

  /* Build each paragraph in record */
  to_paragraph(pi_text, pi_max_line, l_loc_para, l_loc_lines);

  /* Extract Result */
  FOR i IN 1 .. l_loc_lines
  LOOP
    l_return := l_return || l_loc_para(i) || pi_end_paragraph;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN TRIM(CHR(10) FROM l_return);

END wrap_to_paragraph;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.